# match each occurrence of a dot until a single colon

Tags: regex

Take this string

**bob.ted.dave.allan::james.fred: hello.dave**

I need to replace each occurrence of **.** with **#** until I hit a singular ":" not stopping at the namespace '::' but just the ":"

So in the above string, the end result will be 
**bob#ted#dave#allan::james#fred: hello.dave**

currently I have [.] which matches all dots in the string but cant get it to anchor on the single ":"

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure regex solution this can only be done with a variable-width lookbehind pattern, which is supported by only a few regex engines:

```
(?<!(?<!:):(?!:).*)\.
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Crq49C/2

Or if there is always going to be a colon, you can use a positive lookahead pattern instead:

```
\.(?=.*(?<!:):(?!:))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Crq49C/3

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the entire string up until the single `:` with a simple character set match:

`[\w\. :]+(?::{1})`

Then do a replace on all of the `.`'s in the captured string.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xDfstu/1

Answer (score 0):

To just anchor on a single `.` and not stop until seeing exactly one `:` I think
`[.](?=.*:{1})` 
will work. 
This does not work if there is more than one `:` on a line.